# How does ag-Grid add css to elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, ag-grid

When I mouseover some element, such a row for example, in ag-Grid I notice that it adds some inline css to highlight that element.  For example, when the element is not selected the html looks like so:

```
<div class="ag-full-width-viewport" role="presentation" 
style="border-right: 0px solid transparent;"> == $0
```

However, when I mouseover this element it is automatically highlighted and inline css is added:

```
<div class="ag-full-width-viewport" role="presentation" 
style="border-right: 0px solid transparent: border-bottom: 0px solid 
transparent;"> == $0
```

I am wondering how exactly does the api do this.  Where in the source code can I see this logic?  I want to know for the purpose of adding my own css to specific elements within the grid...rather than using the api's `getRowClass()` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/b4353aba1a2405d2133ef0726dc6733596435d9d/src/ts/gridPanel/gridPanel.ts#L864

Found with this search:

[https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/search?utf8=✓&q=transparent+extension%3Ajs+extension%3Ats&type=](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=transparent+extension%3Ajs+extension%3Ats&type=)

You could use your browser developer tools to debug it if you need to. For example in Chrome's Developer Tools, you can right-click that element designated as `$0` (in your question), then "Break on... -> attribute modifications". Once the `style` attribute does change, you'll see where it's coming from.

I do have the feeling that your question is a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though...

Comment: You are correct that the question is an xy problem.  This is because getRowClass() and rowClassRules() does not work as intended. It applies the css class to the top of the html hierarchy, not the specific row you are clicking on.  I don't see any other way of doing this rather than trying to replicate what they did in the source code.